# Guard object in C#

Tags: c#, c++

In C++, it's fairly easy to write a Guard class which takes a reference to a variable (usually a bool) and when the instance object exits scope and gets destructed, the destructor resets the variable to the original value.

```
void someFunction() {

  if(!reentryGuard) {
    BoolGuard(&reentryGuardA, true);
    // do some stuff that might cause reentry of this function
    // this section is both early-exit and exception proof, with regards to restoring
    // the guard variable to its original state
  }
}
```

I'm looking for a graceful way to do this in C# using the disposal pattern (or maybe some other mechanism?)  I'm thinking that passing a delegate to call might work, but seems a bit more error-prone than the guard above.  Suggestions welcome!

Something like:

```
void someFunction() {

  if(!reentryGuard) {
    using(var guard = new BoolGuard(ref reentryGuard, true)) {
      // do some stuff that might cause reentry of this function
      // this section is both early-exit and exception proof, with regards to restoring
      // the guard variable to its original state
    }
  }
}
```

With the understanding that the above code won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct…without unsafe code, you can't save the address of a by-ref parameter. But, depending on how much you can change the overall design, you can create a "guardable" type, such that it's a reference type containing the value to actually guard.

For example:

```
class Program
{
    class Guardable<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; private set; }

        private sealed class GuardHolder<TGuardable> : IDisposable where TGuardable : Guardable<T>
        {
            private readonly TGuardable _guardable;
            private readonly T _originalValue;

            public GuardHolder(TGuardable guardable)
            {
                _guardable = guardable;
                _originalValue = guardable.Value;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                _guardable.Value = _originalValue;
            }
        }    

        public Guardable(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public IDisposable Guard(T newValue)
        {
            GuardHolder<Guardable<T>> guard = new GuardHolder<Guardable<T>>(this);

            Value = newValue;

            return guard;
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Guardable<int> guardable = new Guardable<int>(5);

        using (var guard = guardable.Guard(10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(guardable.Value);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(guardable.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, I like that - define the variable as an augmented type.  I like that it also signals the intent of the variable (more than just the variable name.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a functional (as in lambda-based) way to do it.  Pluses are, no need to use a using:

(note: This is not thread-safe.  If you are looking to keep different threads from running the same code simultaneously, look at the lock statement, the monitor, and the mutex)

```
// usage
GuardedOperation TheGuard = new GuardedOperation() // instance variable
public void SomeOperationToGuard()
{
   this.TheGuard.Execute(() => TheCodeToExecuteGuarded);
}
```

```
    // implementation
    public class GuardedOperation
    {
        public bool Signalled { get; private set; }


        public bool Execute(Action guardedAction)
        {
            if (this.Signalled)
                return false;

            this.Signalled = true;
            try
            {
                guardedAction();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.Signalled = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Here is how you could use the guarded with parameters:

```
public void SomeOperationToGuard(int aParam, SomeType anotherParam)
{
   // you can pass the params to the work method using closure
   this.TheGuard.Execute(() => TheMethodThatDoesTheWork(aParam, anotherParam);
}

private void TheMethodThatDoesTheWork(int aParam, SomeType anotherParam) {}
```

You could also introduce overloads of the Execute method that accept a few different variants of the Action delegate, like Action<T> and Action<T1, T2>

If you need return values, you could introduce overloads of Execute that accept Func<T>

Comment: Okay, interesting, though the downside would be transposing the current context to the GuardOperation (relevant variables, etc.) unless you use an anonymous function.  For short operations, this would work fine.  I'll mark the Guardable as the answer since it's closer to what I was asking for, but this is a good solution as well.

Comment: Cool.  I will also pop in an example of managing parameters via closures.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive your object from [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface and implement it.

*In specific case you are presenting here* `Dispose` will be called as soon as you leave `using` scope.

Example:

```
public class BoolGuard : IDisposable 
{
       .... 
       ...      
        public void Dispose()
        { 
            //DISPOSE IMPLEMANTATION
        }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but that was implied in the question.  I'm wondering about how to elegantly design an object which does the converse assignment when leaving the scope.

Comment: @cunningdave: one time you are able to intercept the moment your object is going to leave the scope, you basically can do whatever you want: clean, reassign to something else....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the sort of thing you'd have to implement yourself - there are no such mechanisms built into  C# or the .NET framework, though I did locate a [deprecated class Guard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.utility.guard.aspx) on MSDN.

This sort of functionality would likely need to use a `Using` statement to operate without passing around an `Action` block, which as you said could get messy. Note that you can only call `using` against and `IDisposable` object, which will then be disposed - the perfect trigger for resetting the value of the object in question.